# Cómo estructurar esta aplicación de React: Funcionalidad de botones evitando complejidad

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actualmente tengo dos "dos vistas" principales en esta aplicación. Una es `<Landing />` que es un componente que muestra que es la pagina principal, y otra es `<PreApp />` , que es un componente que forma otros componentes que muestran la segunda página , y que según si se pulsa un botón tienen algunas modificaciones u otras.

```js
class PreApp extends React.Component{
  state = { TestIsOn: false }

    handleStateUp = (testInOn) => {
        this.setState({ TestIsOn: testInOn })
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar /> 
        {this.state.TestIsOn ? <Test /> : <PreTest />}
        {this.state.TestIsOn ? <FooterTest /> : <Footer handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp} />}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {ButtonClicked: false}

  handleSubmit = (ButtonClicked) => {
    this.setState({ ButtonClicked: ButtonClicked })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.ButtonClicked ? <PreApp /> : <Landing handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

No estoy nada contento como actualmente está estructurada la aplicación, porque la funcionalidad de los botones está ahora mismo anclada a "condicionales". **A mi me gustaría que simplemente funcionasen con un "simple "onClick" te llevasen a x componente.**

Ahora mismo el problema que quería solucionar es que en  hay un condicional que según si el botón "CREAR CUENTA" de  se pulsa, se renderiza el componente `<PreApp />`. Sino `<Landing />` es lo que se muestra. Pero claro ahora quiero tambien añadirle funcionalidad al segundo botón ("HAZ UN TEST"), entonces ya no puedo incluirlo en el condicional ternario porque obviamente sólo permite dos.

Por ejemplo si hago esto, obviamente me renderiza las dos cosas de cada condicional:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  state = {ButtonClicked: false}

  handleSubmit = (ButtonClicked) => {
    this.setState({ ButtonClicked: ButtonClicked })
  }
  handleLogin = (EnteredLogin) => {
    this.setState({EnteredLogin: EnteredLogin})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.ButtonClicked ? <PreApp /> : <Landing handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />}
        {this.state.EnteredLogin ? <Login /> : <Landing handleLogin={this.handleLogin} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

El componente Landing con los dos botones a los que me refiero:

```js
class Landing extends React.Component{
    
   render(){
       return (
        <div>
            <NavBarMain />
            <main>
        <section class="presentation">
          <div class="introduction">
            <div class="intro-text">
              <h1>lore ipsum
                </h1>
              <p>
                  loreimpsum

              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="cta">
              <a><button onClick={() => this.props.handleLogin(true)} class="cta-select">CREAR CUENTA</button></a>
             <a><button onClick={() => this.props.handleSubmit(true)} class="cta-add">HAZ UN TEST</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cover">
            <img src="" alt="matebook" />
          </div>
        </section>
        </main>
        <FooterIndex />
        </div>
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado `react-router`? [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como hay muchas maneras de hacer lo que pides y cada uno en su contexto podría usar una u otra, te voy a poner un ejemplo para que puedas escalar esa funcionalidad.

Ahora mismo el estado que controla qué se muestra es un boleano (true|false)  por lo que solo tienes 2 opciones...

En vez de eso podrías tener en el state una variable tipo string que puedas configurar más ampliamente, por ejemplo:

```
state = {
  selectedView: 'test' // por ejemplo, o 'preapp'...
}
```

en el método donde actualizas el valor en vez de usar true o false, cambia el contenido de `selectedView` a una referencia que luego puedas fácilmente comprobar:

```
changeView = (view) => {
  this.setState({ selectedView: view });
}
```

Y en el render en vez de esos ternarios complejos puedes usar algo así:

```
render() {
  const { selectedView } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
    {selectedView === 'preapp' && <PreApp />}
    {selectedView === 'enteredLogin' && EnteredLogin}
    ... y así sucesivamente
  </div>
  );
}
```

No es la mejor solución, como te comentaba yo usaría `react-router` para esto.

Comment: Gracias, me he decidido por probar con el react-router pero tu idea parecía sencilla. Resulta que estoy probando y cuando pulso en un <Link /> me redirige a la ruta que le pongo en ese link (por ejemplo "/register) y no al componente. Creía que la ruta era "simbólica" para que coincidiese con la declaracion de <Route /> más abajo, pero veo que no. Pero como digo, yo no tengo mas html que el index. Con lo cual solo quiero que vaya a ese componente. O lo del react-router es necesario crear html´s ? Gracias

Comment: No sé muy bien a qué te refieres con crear más HTML's. Con `react-router` cuando te dirige a una ruta te muestra el componente que tú quieras en esa ruta y no otros. Así que entiendo que el único HTML que tienes que mostrar es el JSX de renderizado del propio componente que quieras mostrar.

Comment: Ah, entonces es como pensaba yo. Pues hago exactamente eso y no me muestra el componente. Bueno, voy a probar un poco más y sino ya abro otro hilo ya que esta pregunta es diferente a la original.